# How can I use a method that is not exposed by Xamarin on iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to use a method that exists on `NSString` that is called [`writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407654-writetofile) but [this method is not exposed to Xamarin.iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Foundation.NSString/).

How can I create a binding that will allow me to use this method? All resources that I found explain how to bind libraries.

I am aware there are better ways to write a string to a file but so it is not so much about this method but rather how to bind such methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So at the end I have managed to solve it through a binding library.

I have created a new project of type "Binding Library (iOS)". After that I added a new file `NSStringWriteToFileExtension.cs` and in *Properties* I made sure the *Build Action* is set to `ObjcBindingApiDefinition` and put the following code in there.

```
using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;

namespace Foundation
{
    [Category]
    [BaseType(typeof(NSString))]
    public interface NSStringWriteToFileExtension
    {
        [Export("writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:")]
        bool Write(string filePath, bool atomically, NSStringEncoding encoding, out NSError error);
    }
}
```

This creates a new extension on `NSString` that gives me access to the method.

Answer (score 4):

Calling a method on an ObjC instance is about messaging. You do not directly invoke the method, but the ObjC `objc_msgSend` function will when called with the object to invoke it upon, the selector which describes the method to be invoked, and the parameters of the method.

#### Define the `objc_msgSend` entry point:

Note: This includes the object that you wish to invoke the selector on, the selector created with the selector's name, and then the parameters to be passed

```
// NSString writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:
[DllImport(Constants.ObjectiveCLibrary, EntryPoint = "objc_msgSend")]
static extern bool NSString_bool_obj_msgSend_IntPtr_bool_NSStringEncoding_IntPtr(
        IntPtr target,
        IntPtr selector,
        IntPtr path,
        bool atomically,
        NSStringEncoding encoding,
        IntPtr error
);
```

#### Create the matching selector:

Note: Cache this if you will be calling it repeatedly

```
var nsStringWriteToFileSelector = new Selector("writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:");
```

#### Calling Example:

```
// Selector for NSString writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:
var nsStringWriteToFileSelector = new Selector("writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:");

// Parameters to be passed via `objc_msgSend` 
var nsString = new NSString("StackOverflow");
var path = new NSString("nsstring.txt");
var error = new NSError();

// Call objc_msgSend with the object, selector and parameters
var success = NSString_bool_obj_msgSend_IntPtr_bool_NSStringEncoding_IntPtr(
    nsString.Handle,
    nsStringWriteToFileSelector.Handle,
    path.Handle,
    true,
    NSStringEncoding.UTF8,
    error.Handle);

if (success && File.Exists(path.ToString()))
    Console.WriteLine("success");
else
    Console.WriteLine(error.Description);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is not was I was looking for it. It is using underlying runtime to execute the method and it is too cumbersome. I have managed to find a solution by myself at the end.

Comment: @TomášLinhart FYI: This is what your method is doing via the `[Export]` attribute.